# I cant render and object from state, ReactJS with functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-functional-component, json-server

With this function i filter some objects from an API

```
const consultarAPI = async () => {
try {
  const consulta = await fetch(URL);
  const respuesta = await consulta.json();
  // Aqui se filtran las noticias
  const noticiasFiltradas = respuesta.filter(
    (noticia) => noticia.categoria === categoria
  );
  setNoticias(noticiasFiltradas);
  setDestacada(noticiasFiltradas[noticiasFiltradas.lenght-1])
  
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

};

I dont know whats wrong. The state 'noticias' recieves and array of objects, and 'destacada' recieves the last object of the array.

On the app, states of my component shows exactly how i expected. But, if i do this

```
<h4>{destacada.titulo}</h4>
```

cause i need to render the title of that particular object. The app crash and i get this error.
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'titulo' of undefined**

**How is it undefined**? It worked perfectly seconds before i tried to render the object. Please i need help.
These are my states:

```
const [destacada, setDestacada]=useState({});


const [noticias, setNoticias] = useState([]);



const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState("");
```

Comment: Check that noticiasFiltradas[noticiasFiltradas.lenght-1] returns the value you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

You have typo here

```
setDestacada(noticiasFiltradas[noticiasFiltradas.lenght-1])
```

This is why `destacada` is undefined.

So change `noticiasFiltradas.lenght-1` to `noticiasFiltradas.length-1`

Comment: Sorry! I typed that wrong while writing the question. On my code is typed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve solved the problem. Instead of write `<h4>{destacada.titulo}</h4>`, do `<h4>{destacada && destacada.titulo}</h4>`